# Can we migrate the existing solo chain blocks to another substrate chain?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain, solo-chain

I've been working on data migration from the existing solo chain to the Relay Chain. I've already fetched most of the data but i need to know about fetching the blocks. Is there any way to fetch the blocks too, and add them in the new chain.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been working on the data migration from the existing solo chain to the Relay Chain.

If you mean from solo chain to a parachain, yes you could keep the block history. You would need to migrate from your solo chain directly to a parachain. This way you could keep your entire history of blocks and state.

There is currently not an easy guide to follow. [Here](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/) are some information.